# How to determine the CSP/KSP and key container of the private key when a certificate is loaded at run time?

Tags: c#, private-key, x509certificate2

Given when we load a X509Certificate2

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFile,"somepassphrase");
```

the private key is persisted unless X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet is specified (I'm unable to specify this option since there seems to be a bug - I get 'No credentials are available in the security package' when I submit my https post request), I need to make sure the private key is remove off the machine when I'm done with it. I'm using the c# sample code provided here to delete the key: https://www.pkisolutions.com/deleting-certificates-from-windows-certificate-store-programmatically-powershell-and-c/,
I want to check manually this is in fact deleted? How can I determine the CSP/KSP and key container of where the private key is or any other ways to verify it's deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an `X509Certificate2` object with private key and key is persisted, a key file is added to one of key storage locations on file system. Exact key location is determined by key provider and context (current user or local machine). Paths for lookup are described in [Key Storage and Retrieval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval#key-directories-and-files) article.

When you delete the key using the code in your referenced article (in fact, I'm the author of the article you referenced), the file is deleted from file system.

If the key is stored on a hardware device, such as smart card, HSM, TPM, you need to use device vendor-supplied APIs or tools to check if the key is actually deleted.

Comment: Given I haven't specified the X509KeyStorageFlags, the default is UserKeySet, which means the key is stored in C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys... how to determine which of those keys are the one that belongs to my certificate's private key?

Comment: `certutil -user -store my "{certSerial}"` and find `unique container name` field.

Comment: Does this only work if the certificate was imported into the Windows Certificate Store? Does the line of code I've included in this post actually import it into the store??

Comment: Tried it, got 'Object not found'

Comment: certutil requires the certificate to be installed in certificate store. Another option (which doesn't require deep dive in code) is to sort items in folder by date. Call the code line and find that new file is added. Then call API to delete the key and find that the file is deleted.

Comment: Ok, sounds like there isn't already a method of determine where the private key file is.

Comment: No, there is no method. What you can do is to get file name, but not exact file location.

Comment: Regarding your info about if a private key is stored on a hardware device, I should check that the key is actually deleted using your code.   I am building a tooling app that submits csrs and then imports the certificate into the windows cert store with private key protected by TPM (using certtutil -csp "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" ...).   From my readings, this still stores the private key on disk but it is protected by the TPM and only that TPM can decrypt it.   So if I delete that file with your code, what is it that I need to verify that is specific to the TPM?

Comment: I think that's enough for TPM or, for example, nCipher HSM. Smart cards (most) and SafeNet Luna HSM don't store encrypted keys on file system.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses,  could you please clarify what you mean 'what you can do is to get file name, but not exact file location'... what file name is this?  The private key file name?  how do we get that?  how would this help determine the location?